# How to view .dat file generated by c++ program?

Tags: c++, fstream, file-handling

I am learning c++ file handling. First I generated a .txt file using fstream library and viewed data on notepad but when I created a something (a .dat file) unfortunately I am unable to open that file into any text editor, but I can get data from that file in C++. Is there any file viewer or way by using which I can view the .dat file?

```
void display_all()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\tDISPLAY ALL RECORD !!!\n\n";
    fp.open("Shop.dat",ios::in);
    while(fp.read((char*)&pr,sizeof(product)))
    {
        pr.show_product();
        cout<<"\n\n====================================\n";
        getch();
    }
    fp.close();
    getch();
}
```

The above function is showing all  the data in my Shop.dat file but when I open that file directly my OS in not determining what type of file is it.

Comment: What were you *expecting* to see?

Comment: If I understand your question, this code can read your file but you're looking for an OS utility that is designed to open the same kind of file?

Comment: yes you are right this code is reading data from file named as Shop.dat but  my question is that how can i directly open that file into text editor to view content of that file?

Comment: You can not open a binary file in a text editor and view the contents in a meaningful way.

Comment: so is there any hex Editor and viewer that can i use  ?

Comment: You need to write another program to display it, unless it is entirely composed of text.

Comment: ***so is there any hex Editor and viewer that can i use ?*** That will dump the hex of the file but it will still not be very human readable. Text will be readable (on the ascii side) but integers, doubles ... will not be that easily visible.

Comment: you mean to say that we can not view that files content?

Comment: Here is a hexdump: http://superuser.com/questions/468456/how-can-i-view-the-binary-contents-of-a-file-natively-in-windows-7-is-it-possi

Comment: ***you mean to say that we can not view that files content?*** Variables that are not text will look like garbage (unless you know how to decode them).

Comment: @drescherjm interesting  let me test that tool for further discussion thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've got *your* personal file format and your program is the only way to view the information stored like this. Why? Because there's no program that knows the sctructure and sizes of the fields that your own program produces. The only way to view the data - create your own *notepad*.

Another example: in my program I use json format to save and load information (using Qt). This information can be stored as *plain text* and as *binary file*. But it doesn't mean that every program that understands json can read *binary* file and treat it's content as a *plain-json-text*. Well, if I want to check the content of the *binary* file I use my own little utility that converts *binary* file to the *plain text*. And that's what *you* can do for your own purposes - small convertion utility or a simple read-only "notepad".

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to view the hex dump of the .dat file.  You need to open the file in binary mode

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

        int main()
        {
           ifstream infile;
           infile.open("Shop.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);

           //Read file
           char buffer[100];;
           inFile.read (buffer, 100);
           if (!inFile) 
           {
             // An error occurred
           }


       return 0;
    }
```

EDIT: What IDE are you using?  In Visual Studio, you can see the hex dump of a .dat (assuming it's a binary file) by just clicking on the file (IIRC).

Comment: I am using code-block. Does code-block has any such kind of feature?